# Adding value to array in C doesn't work

Tags: c, arrays

I want to add a string to a string array but it doesn't work.
Currently, I have that code:

```
void splitArray(char *strings, char *delimiter) {
int i = 0;
char newArray[MAXCHARS];
char* pch = NULL;

pch = strtok(strings, delimiter);

while (pch != NULL)
{
    // doesn't work; Exception: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
    newArray = pch;
    printf("%s\n", pch);
    pch = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
}
}
```

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: By `strcpy`'ing pch into newArray? And by the way, `char newArray[MAXCHARS];` is not a string array, it's an array of characters - also known as a string...

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem

Comment: Good :) You should accept @cloud1's answer in that case as he says basically the same thing.

Comment: Why add something to an array when the array is lost when the function returns?  What are you really trying to achieve? (btw - you dont have an array of strings)

Comment: The parameter should be a string array and then I split it by the delimiter. Afterwards I want to return the splitted array to the main program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use strcpy to copy string to char array.